# Why is onActivityResult triggered before activity even starts?

Tags: android, android-activity, barcode-scanner, onactivityresult

I have an app that needs to scan a barcode to get a code before it can continue. I use this code to start the scanning activity:

```
finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
        finish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View viewParam) {

                /*Prompt the user to scan the barcode */
                new AlertDialog.Builder(Visit.this)
                .setMessage("Please Scan the clients barcode to complete the visit")
                .setPositiveButton("Scan Barcode", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Start the scan application
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Execute some method call
                        Toast.makeText(Visit.this, "Scan declined...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .show();
                /* End of Scan prompt */
            }
        });
```

The above code sets a listener on a button labeled `finished`. When the button is clicked, it displays a prompt asking the user to scan a barcode or cancel.

Clicking on the <kbd>Scan Barcode</kbd> button starts a new activity which starts the scan.

I have the following code set up to read the result of the scan on the return from the scan:

```
/* Return from scanning barcode */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
;
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        String result = extras.getString("SCAN_RESULT");
      }
      Toast.makeText(Visit.this, "request code: "+requestCode+" result code = "+resultCode+ "\nRESULT_OK: "+Activity.RESULT_OK, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Which very simply (for now) outputs the activity result in a toast message.

The problem I'm having is that the `onActivityResult` method is triggered as soon as I press the scan barcode button.

The scanning process works fine as I can see the results of the scan in the logcat., however because it is triggered too soon the `onActivityResult` method never gets the scan result and the result code is always -1

Am I missing a step here? is there someway of getting to `onActivityResult` to wait until the activity actual finishes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the barcode scanner I am using has a particular bug in it for tab interfaces with single instance in the manifest which is how I had it.

Removing the single instance stipulation allowed me to do a hack on it thats working perfectly.

Comment: You saved me at least an hour of debugging with this! I used it in ViewFlipper's nested fragment and I had the same issue. Removing single instance fixed this problem.

Comment: @pkk Glad to have been of some use to someone!

Comment: thx! android:launchMode="singleTask" also cause this kind of problem