# android - launch an activity of another app to get it's result

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launch

I have two applications, A and B.

From A, I'm launching B for a result, using the following code:

```
Intent fmIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.B");
fmIntent.putExtra("hello", "world");
startActivityForResult(fmIntent, REQUEST_TEST);
```

From B, I'm doing the following:

```
getIntent().putExtra("completed", true);
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

If I do the above for an activity within the same app, it works as expected.

However, since its two different apps, I receive an empty intent with no data and an unset result code. How should I edit the above to ensure that one intent is maintained throughout?

Comment: Have you followed the guide here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html ?

Comment: What makes you think that `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` would ever return something suitable for use by `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: I just went by guessing it would.

Comment: Let me take a look at the intent filters.

Comment: I figured it out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204577/launch-activity-using-custom-intent-throwing-activity-not-found-exception

Comment: Did you can solve this problem question ? Now I have problem the same like this your question.if you have solve this question pls share your code.Thanks

Comment: @MinTheinWin I used deep links for this. This looks like an android limitation.

Comment: @judepereira What you mean? You can't help me?

Comment: No I can't. The way around this is to use a deep link.

Answer (score 11):

Use `setFlags(0)` to clean all flags which can be created by `getLaunchIntentForPackage`:

```
Intent fmIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.B");
fmIntent.setFlags(0);
fmIntent.putExtra("hello", "world");
startActivityForResult(fmIntent, REQUEST_TEST);
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is provided in a related question "[Android onActivityResult triggered before activity even starts!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524140/android-onactivityresult-triggered-before-activity-even-starts)". Create the intent this way:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.example.B", "com.example.B.ActivityB");
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 600);
```

I was facing the same problem and solved this way.

Comment: How do you get the result from it?